# Use this account everywhere on your device

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-outlook

I've got this Dialog Box when I enter my password for my @outlook account in the Outlook program.

It says :

**Use this account everywhere on your device
Windows will remember your account and make it easier to sign in to apps and websites. Clicking Next means that you'll be able to find a lost device, sync your settings to other devices, and ask Cortana for help.**

But I don't want to use a Microsoft Account on my computer or on any other Office app. I just want to be able to use my mail address.

This is the image I have to show the problem:

[image: Outlook problem]

How can I achieve the fact of using this adress **only** with Outlook and no other app?

**EDIT :** Added image

Comment: Ignore or cancel？

Comment: I can only click "Next" or "Microsoft Apps Only", or close the windows but then, the program won't sync emails

Answer (score 0):

It looks you are getting something like the below screenshot, you can just click "This app only":
[image]

Reference:
[What Does the "Use this account everywhere on your device" Dialog Do?](https://superuser.com/questions/1389113/what-does-the-use-this-account-everywhere-on-your-device-dialog-do)

Comment: Hi. I'll try to put a picture up later. I'm not getting exactly this. The only option below in yellow spells "Microsoft App only". I don't have the option for "This app only".

Comment: Maybe you can try "Microsoft apps only", and then configure the "Stop signing in to all Microsoft apps automatically" as per this article: https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/5375-switch-microsoft-account-windows-10-a.html. BTW, it's actually a Windows 10 issue IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is years later but I had the same issue and I fixed it by going to Settings > Accounts > Your Info and clicking on the "Sign in with a Microsoft account instead" link, but NOT actually signing in--and simply leaving the window that appears up. Then I went back to Outlook and tried to sync again, it asked me to sign in which I did, but it did not present me with the prompt to use this account everywhere anymore.